# When is constructor's code of a class defined in global space running?

Tags: c++

```
class TestClass
{
public:
    int x, y;
    TestClass();

};

TestClass::TestClass()
{
    cout << "TestClass ctor" << endl;
}

TestClass GlobalTestClass;

int main()
{   

    cout << "main " << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

In this code as known first output will be `"TestClass ctor"`.

My question: Does the ctor function call codes run before `main()` (I mean, does entry point change ?) , or right after `main()` and before the executable statements or is there different mechanism ? (Sorry for English)

Comment: Is there any distinction between the two?

Comment: A fun test:  put a call to abort() (or similar) inside your constructor, and run the program; when the program crashes, invoke the debugger and have it print a stack trace to tell you what the call stack was when the crash occurred.  That should answer your question (at least as far as what happens under your particular environment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question as stated is not very meaningful, because

- `main` is not the machine code level entry point to the program (`main` is called by the same code that e.g. executes constructors of non-local static class type variables), and
- the notion of “right after `main()` and before the executable statements” isn't very meaningful: the executable statements are *in* `main`.

Generally, in practice you can count on the static variable being initialized before `main` in your concrete example, but the standard does not guarantee that.

C++11 §3.6.2/4:

> **”** It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with static storage
>   duration is done before the first statement of `main`. If the initialization is deferred to some point in time
>   after the first statement of `main`, it shall occur before the first odr-use (3.2) of any function or variable
>   defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized.

It's a fine point whether the automatic call of `main` qualifies as *odr-use*. I would think not, because one special property of `main` is that it cannot be called (in valid code), and its address cannot be taken.

Apparently the above wording is in support of dynamically loaded libraries, and constitutes the only support of such libraries.

In particular, I would be wary of using thread local storage with dynamically loaded libraries, at least until I learned more about the guarantees offered by the standard in that respect.

Comment: i guess i could not express myself correctly but the reference you gave is my answer. right after`main()`, sentence is not meaningful as you said, i wanted to say "is compiler adding any code after main() like `main() ctorcall(); /****/ executable statements;`"

Comment: @ApprenticeTheSecond: Not exactly, but `main` returns to code that calls `exit`, and `exit` in turn causes [some cleanup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit) to be performed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, objects with static storage duration are initialized before `main()`, so indeed the "entry point" is before `main()`. See e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration

In fact (although not recommended), you can run a whole program with a trivial `main(){}`, by putting everything in global instances.

Comment: Re "objects with static storage duration are initialized before main()", this is true *in practice* with all implementations I know, as long as no libraries are loaded dynamically (which isn't generally supported by the standard anyway). Still the C++ standard explicitly notes that this is not guaranteed.